# Using bootstrap-sass in Rails, Bootstrap / Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

trying to learn rails (and I'm still really early on in my development) but I've hit a wall and I'm scratching my head.

I'm trying to leverage bootstrap via bootstrap-sass, and it seems like when I use [the default bootstrap navigation bar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)  I can get the bar to render - but it's not interactive.  It looks like javascript isn't working properly, but I'm not sure why.

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc


group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

application.css

```
  *= require_tree .
  *= require_self
```

app/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

config/application.rb

```
module FamilyLunch
   class Application < Rails::Application
     config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Family Lunch | <%= yield(:title) %> </title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class='container'>
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %> 
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
    <% end %> 
<%= yield %>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` to `application.js`.

Comment: Ahh perfect.  Oversight on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the JavaScript you have to add `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` to `application.js` like this :

**app/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

For Solidus create an **app/assets/spree/frontend/all.js** and include:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

this will override the **app/assets/application.js**